# How to Distribute Task Types Evenly to Employees Using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Could someone please help me with this problem? I've been trying some solutions and Googling, but so far I haven't found a solution.

I have a list of tasks and they need to be assigned to staff members.
There are several task types and my goal is to distribute each task type evenly to all staff members.

As an example, I prepared this data:

[image: sample]

My goal is for each staff to get (roughly) the same number of tasks of each type.

Currently manual workflow:

1. Count available task per category.
   Starting with Type A The first category is Type A, and there are 10 of them in the example.
2. Divide to staff members. 10 / 3 = 3.33
   For uneven divisions, the remainder will go to a staff member. So 1 person will get 4 tasks while the other 2 people gets 3 tasks each.
3. Assign names to the "Task Assignment" column based on the calculation above.

[image]

4. Repeat the steps above for each task type.

Final result:

[image]

In the actual dataset, I could be dealing with 1000 - 1500 tasks, around 10 types, and up to a dozen staff members available for the day.
And this has to be done 1x a day, every day.
Using the manual method mentioned above is quite tedious and error-prone.

I'm hoping there is a way to use formulas to automate the assignment. I tried randomizing the assignment, but as the name suggests, it didn't provide a consistently even distribution.

If you have any ideas on how to solve this, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you able to share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi @iansedano, I tried randomizing using =INDEX($E$2:$E$4,RANDBETWEEN(1,3)) with E2:E4 being the list of staff members. When applied to the "Task Assignment" column, I ended up with a random assignment on each row. However, the aim here is to get an even distribution of tasks in each type, so it's not the best solution. Any thoughts on something I could try?

Comment: I believe that the answer below is the simplest solution. Just creating a sequence of repeating names over a sorted task list is more efficient than calculating the number of each type of task and assigning it manually. Or is there a reason you need to calculate the types separately?

Comment: I think so too, I'm going to use the solution below. It should help me achieve the end goal: even distribution of tasks within each task types. I did manual calculation because that was the only method that I'm aware of, the method below should be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is to repeat list of available staff along the list of task types sorted by task type.

Like this:
[image]

All the job is done in column C

```
=transpose(split(rept(join("|";D3:D)&"|";ceiling(count(A3:A)/COUNTA(D3:D)));"|";1;1))
```

Formula takes number of tasks: count(A3:A), divides it by number of staff available: counta(d3:d), then divides one by another and rounds up using ceiling formula.
This is used to determine how many times list of Staff available should be repeated.
Repetition is made by first joining together this list (join with | as separator), then repeating (rept) and splitting (split by | ). Finally transposing to have all values in one column.

Columns F to I are just for testing to see if lists of task assignments are similar.

You can play with my solution here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OaNiACC8hTShyCLdXj7TmZywQAKMuu7dknVgEnT-ZqE/copy

Comment: Hi @Krzysztof Dołęgowski, thanks for the solution. I think this may work, let me give it a try on the original dataset. I really appreciate your help by looking into this!